# REST Web service call is not working in Java 1.7

Tags: web-services, rest, playframework, jdk1.7

I am trying to use a RESTful API in Java, which is working in Java 1.6 and Java 1.8 but not working in Java 1.7.

My code:

```java
import play.libs.F.Promise;
import play.libs.WS;
import play.libs.WS.Response;
import play.libs.WS.WSRequestHolder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String ADD_CART_URL ="https://stagconnect.acehubpaymentservices.com/gateway/v3/payments/";
        String postString = "{\"action\":\"payment\", \"header\":{\"businessId\":\"4578895\"}, \"body\":{\"transaction\":{\"trackingCode\":\"9090-90-9876\", \"type\":\"SINGLE\", \"brandId\":\"1010\", \"amount\":\"5.00\", \"currencyCode\":\"EUR\",\"countryCode\":\"NL\"}, \"card\":{\"holderName\":\"John Smith\", \"number\":\"4907639999990022\", \"expiryMonth\":\"12\", \"expiryYear\":\"2017\", \"cvv\":\"029\"}}}";
        String certificatesTrustStorePath = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts";
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", certificatesTrustStorePath);

        System.out.println("ws call start");
        Promise<Response>  promise = WS.url(ADD_CART_URL)
                .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .setHeader("Authorization", "Basic S2FjaHluZwedYzpEQEk1secvdfVQ=")
                .post(postString);
        String responseText = promise.get(20000L).getBody();
        System.out.println(responseText);
        System.out.println("WS Call End \n");   
    }
}
```

Error with Java 1.7:

```
 ws call start
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException:    Futures timed out after [20000 milliseconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:96)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:58)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:86)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:86)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.ready(package.scala:86)
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise.await(Promise.scala:134)
    at play.libs.F$Promise.get(F.java:213)
    at play.libs.F$Promise.get(F.java:224)
    at com.kachyng.processor.AcaptureTest.main(AcaptureTest.java:24)
```

Comment: Which version of play framework you are using? Share maven or gradle dependency. Take a look at the changelog https://www.playframework.com/changelog

Comment: If you post a WS call to a payment services hub, you probably don't want to expose the password of KachyngInc on the internet.

Comment: The play framework version is important since we need to know what version of Scala is involved, the timeout is in a Scala Promise

Comment: @NickVanderhoven Thanks. Its a dummy account for testing.

Comment: Play version - 2.1.4  Scala -2.10.0. Also its not about time out am not able to connect with java 1.7. With the same version of play and scala am able to get response from java 1.6 and 1.8